# Why a segue isn't performed

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view that I want to make interactable that when the user touches him, he will perform a segue. Why isn't the code working.

```
@IBOutlet weak var HistoryCategory: UIView!
    var historyTapGesture: UIGestureRecognizer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.historyTapGesture = UIGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(chooseCategoryViewController.openHistoryQuest(tap:)))
        HistoryCategory.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        HistoryCategory.addGestureRecognizer(historyTapGesture)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @objc func openHistoryQuest(tap: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "history", sender: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget your view controller class is the one to perform your segue, so you need to set “self” as the target and sender, and as @rmaddy mentioned make it a tap gesture recognizer.

Simply replace these two lines:

```
self.historyTapGesture = UIGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(chooseCategoryViewController.openHistoryQuest(tap:)))


performSegue(withIdentifier: "history", sender: nil)
```

With:

```
self.historyTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(chooseCategoryViewController.openHistoryQuest(tap:)))


performSegue(withIdentifier: "history", sender: self)
```

Comment: You need to create a specific type of gesture. It's probably supposed to be a tap gesture.